# Add support for graphical playing card representations

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get a renderer for Cards?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/696/can-we-get-a-renderer-for-cards)

Could we get some sort of support for automated inline graphics representing playing cards?  The visual aid could be helpful in clarifying questions and/or answers that involve specific hand combinations.  One such question I'd consider using it for is here:

[Counting multi-runs in cribbage](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/counting-multi-runs-in-cribbage)

For example, this code:

`[cards:AS,AC,2H,3H,6D]`

Could resolve to:

[image: Ace of Spades][image: Ace of Clubs][image: Two of Hearts][image: Three of Hearts][image: Six of Diamonds]

(Images from http://www.stevedawson.com/poker-hands.php)

Personally, I'd prefer the cards to be slightly larger so that they're more readable on high-resolution screens.  But, the above is a good example of the feature I'm requesting.

Comment: Yes, this would be great, and has already been asked. Please check out the linked question and see what you think of balpha's concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I didn't see it pop up as a suggestion when I wrote this thread.  I think @balpha's concerns are mainly centered around a proposal to convert free text into card images.  My suggestion completely avoids that problem by requiring Markdown-style tags, with a defined format, to generate the card images.